# NopCommerce and DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, nopcommerce

I have both nopCommerce and DotNetNuke installed on my server. All I need is to be able to share the users between both apps.

can you tell me the easiest solution to make a bridge between them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you should take a look at: 
http://www.sysdatanet.com/nopCommerce/DotNetNuke_nopCommerce.aspx

I haven't used it but it seems like it might be a good approach.

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer. I'd be interested in hearing your experience. Though now that NOPCommerce is converting to MVC, not sure this is a good idea any more.

Answer (score 1):

I am evaluating the same solution, but it doesn't look like NopCommerce and DNN integration is simple or practical. The NopCommerce user data base does not integrate with DNN. Here are some comments I have gleaned:

"*I felt that integrating it [nopCommerce] into DNN was a step that could cause a massive volume of work, which would need maintaining constantly.*"
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/118/threadid/346959/scope/posts.aspx

"*I managed to install nopCommerce yesterday.
I installed today DotNetNuke in the root of my webspace and this has its own web.config file.
Now of course I can't get both applications running at the same time. I have to rename one of the web.config files to get the other app to work and so on.*"
http://www.nopcommerce.com/Boards/Topic.aspx?TopicID=2712

" *you have to know that this will be a hell of a lot of work [to integrate DNN & nopCommerce], as you need to create lots and lots of DNN modules.
Basically the complete NopCommerceWeb-Directory has to be rebuilt for DNN. "*

*"Converting to modules... yikes.  That's a DNN dream, but maintaining nopCommerce upgrades would be outrageous!*"
http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/390/options-to-integrate-with-dnn-as-a-module-anyone-done-that-before.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with nopcommerce but you have a couple options.  If nopCommerce uses the ASP .Net membership tables to track user data you can configure a custom DotNetNuke authentication provider that would use your other database instead.  This may be the first thing you want to look into, and could be a little work or a lot of work.

Alternatively depending on how nopcommerce does it's password encryption you could try and get both the systems using a similar hashing system and then use SQL Server triggers to make users in the other system, update information, passwords etc.

In DotNetNuke you can turn off password encryption and save it as plain text. THat would be a lot easier to sync passwords if nopCommerce can do it.  But obviously not as secure and not necessarily advised.

Comment: Nopcommerce has override the menmbership provider and they are using their own tables instead of asp.net memebership one.